# Oracle DataAccess Manager exception

Tags: c#, oracle

I am getting null exception executing this code

```
using (OracleConnection oracleConnection = _baseRepository.GetConnection())
{
   using (OracleCommand cmd = oracleConnection.CreateCommand())
   { 
       cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
       cmd.BindByName = true;
       cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT GUSER.GID
                               FROM GUSER
                               WHERE GUSER.AZURESUBID = :AZURESUBID";
       cmd.Prepare();
       cmd.Parameters.Clear();
       cmd.Parameters.Add("AZURESUBID", model.SubId);

       try
       {
           oracleConnection.Open();

           // Get the GID 
           var gId = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();

           //If gId has value we will insert all the subsCode/Values for the same gId in this table
           if (gId != null)
           {
               DataTable dt = new DataTable();
               dt.Columns.Add("GID");
               dt.Columns.Add("SUBSCODE");
               dt.Columns.Add("SUBSVALUE");

               for (int i = 0; i < model.SubscriptionCode.Count; i++)
               {
                   DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                   dr["GID"] = gId;
                   dr["SUBSCODE"] = model.SubscriptionCode[i].SubsCode;
                   dr["SUBSVALUE"] = model.SubscriptionCode[i].value ? "Y" : "N";
                   dt.Rows.Add(dr);
               }

               string[] ids = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
               string[] subsCodes = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
               string[] subsValues = new string[dt.Rows.Count];

               for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
               {
                   ids[j] = gId.ToString();
                   subsCodes[j] = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[j]["SUBSCODE"]);
                   subsValues[j] = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[j]["SUBSVALUE"]);
               }

               OracleParameter id = new OracleParameter();
               id.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
               id.Value = ids;

               OracleParameter subsCode = new OracleParameter();
               subsCode.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
               subsCode.Value = subsCodes;

               OracleParameter subsValue = new OracleParameter();
               subsValue.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
               subsValue.Value = subsValues;

               cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
               cmd.CommandText= @"INSERT INTO USER_COMMSUBSCRIPTIONS (GID, SUBSCODE, SUBSVALUE) VALUES (:1, :2, :3)";
               cmd.ArrayBindCount = subsValues.Length;
               cmd.Prepare();
               cmd.Parameters.Clear();
               cmd.Parameters.Add(id);
               cmd.Parameters.Add(subsCode);
               cmd.Parameters.Add(subsValue);
               int retval = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

               if (retval > 0)
               {
                   isSuccess = true;
               }
           }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
       }
       finally
       {
           oracleConnection.Close();
       }
       return isSuccess;
   }
}
```

The `gId` has a value so the if condition is true but for the bulk insert on the line `int retval = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();` I am getting null exception. I am positive that column names match on the database. Is there anyway I can get the actual exception or any log I can see in Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: Which is the line that throws the exception? Also I'd remove that empty catch, it may be hiding the actual error

Comment: it throws exception on int retval = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();